# I can't insert to mysql db in Pipeline scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, mysql-python

I use Pipeline in scrapy to insert item into db, but It doesn't work.
I use twisted.adbapi with settings:

DB_SERVER = 'MySQLdb'
DB_CONNECT = {
    'db': 'vcinema_v4',
    'user': 'root',
    'passwd': 'my-secret-pw',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'charset': 'utf8',
    'use_unicode': True
}

class MySQLPipeline(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    dbargs = settings.get('DB_CONNECT')
    db_server = settings.get('DB_SERVER')
    dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(db_server, **dbargs)

    self.dbpool = dbpool

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    assert isinstance(item, CityItem)
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
    return item

def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    print "db connected-==============>"
    tx.execute("select * from city where name=%s" % (item['name']))
    result = tx.fetchOne()
    if result:
        log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    else:
        tx.execute("""INSERT INTO city(name) VALUES(%s)""", (item['name']))
        log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    print "db end"

def handle_error(self, e):
    log.err(e)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't work? Does it show any error? Your code seems to log some messages, what messages do you obtain?

Comment: Post more details about the issue

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `.commit()` call?

Comment: http://sscce.org/